# How do I add a simple textarea in grid in admin panel?

Tags: grid, magento-1

This is my function:

```
public function _prepareToRender()
{
        $this->addColumn('note', array(
            'header'           => Mage::helper('mynamespace_mymodule')->__('Note'),
            'align'            => 'center',
            'renderer'         => 'mymodule/adminhtml_form_field_content',
            'index'            => 'note',
        ));
}
```

and this is the content of the Content.php file:

```
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Form_Field_Content extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Input
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
      //......
    }
}
```

I am not sure if i extended the right class in order to create a textarea in my grid. Also I do not know what I have to write in my render function. Can you help me and explain me how do i create a textarea in a grid in Magento ? Thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Grid.php file

```
protected function _prepareColumns()

  {
      $this->addColumn('note', array(
            'header'           => Mage::helper('mynamespace_mymodule')->__('Note'),
            'align'            => 'center',
            'renderer'         => 'mymodule/adminhtml_form_field_content',
            'index'            => 'note',
        ));
```

Create Renderer file:

```
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Form_Field_Content extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Input
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $html = parent::render($row);

        $html .= '<textarea name="textarea_'.$row->getId().'" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>';

         return $html;
    }
}
```